# Difference between returning dispatch function or returning a

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning redux and i'm reading a `react/redux` source-code. in `actions/Video.js` file it has this code:

```
export const startDownloading = url => dispatch => {
  ipcRenderer.send("video:url", { url });
  dispatch({
    type: START_DOWNLOADING
  });
};

export const getVideoInfo = info => {
  return { type: GET_VIDEO_INFO, payload: info };
};
```

So what's the difference between:

```
export const startDownloading = url => dispatch => {
  ipcRenderer.send("video:url", { url });
  dispatch({
    type: START_DOWNLOADING
  });
};
```

and

```
export const startDownloading = url => {
  ipcRenderer.send("video:url", { url });
  return {
    type: START_DOWNLOADING
  };
};
```

I mean, when we should return an object and when we should call dispatch function in an `action` file?

Answer (score 0):

the difference relies on how to fire a change in your store,
by default calling an action will not fire the event that is going to be handle by the reducer

so you call `dispatch`  either and object or a function

function

```js
export const someFunction = () => ({type: 'actioncreator'})
dispatch(someFunction())
```

object

```js
dispatch({type: 'actioncreator'}
```

you can dispatch actions inside a component or inside a actions folder